# What is more performant Canvas.drawText or updating textview

Tags: java, android, canvas, textview, drawtext

I'm currently working on an app that needs to update a text value several times per second, currently i'm updating a textview every time it needs to, I was wondering if `Canvas.drawtext()` is more performant for this case.
I tried googling but didn't found a conclusive answer.

I also would like to know which of the two is suited best for what cases.

Comment: Have you tried actually measuring the difference? Also, are you having an actual performance issue or are you optimizing for a case that may not be necessary?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I've tried to see with the two side by side but didn't notice a difference.
about the performance issue, currently i'm not facing any on the devices i've tried but I fear that may be possible on older devices.

Comment: Have you tried profiling each separately in Android Studio? As a Textview is a view, there will probably be significantly more work as it could be re-measured (costly) and laid out again before ultimately it would call Canvas.drawText. Therefore directly calling Canvas.drawText should be less costly.

Comment: @Andrew I have not tried that, but you've inspired me to do it, I will be back when I have conclusive answers